# Help in reducing given matrix to a particular form

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given a matrix, which has been partitioned as follows
$$\textbf{K} = \begin{bmatrix}\textbf{K}_{mm} & \textbf{K}_{ms}\\\textbf{K}_{sm} & \textbf{K}_{ss}\end{bmatrix}$$
Here,
$K_{mm}$ has size $m * m$,
$K_{ms}$ has size $m*n$,
Total matrix dimensions are $(m+n)*(m+n)$

Now, I want to reduce it to the following form via a product of elementary matrices

$$\begin{bmatrix}\textbf{K}_{mm} & \textbf{K}_{ms}\\\textbf{K}_{sm} & \textbf{K}_{ss}\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}\textbf{A} & \textbf{0} \\ \textbf{B} & \textbf{I}\end{bmatrix}$$

The book I am referring to (on Guyan Condesnation), says this is a consequence of Gauss-Jordan elimination. I do not see the relation between this reduction and the row reduced echelon form, which is the GJE product. Can someone shed light on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, let's see
$$
\left( \begin{array}{c | c}
I & 0 \\ \hline
-A_{BL} A_{TL}^{-1} & I
\end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c | c}
A_{TL} & A_{TR} \\ \hline
A_{BL} & A_{BR} 
\end{array} \right)
=
\left( \begin{array}{c | c}
A_{TL} & A_{TR} \\ \hline
0  & \widetilde A_{BR}
\end{array} \right)
$$
That is a block version of Gauss-Jordon step.

Then
$$
\left( \begin{array}{c | c}
I & -A_{TR} \widetilde A_{BR}^{-1} \\ \hline
0 & I
\end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{c | c}
A_{TL} & A_{TR} \\ \hline
0  & \widetilde A_{BR}
\end{array} \right)
=
\left( \begin{array}{c | c}
A_{TL} & 0 \\ \hline
0  & \widetilde A_{BR}
\end{array} \right)
$$
which is also a block version of a Gauss-Jordan step.

This is better than what you were asked to do.  And,  I think, uses nicer notations!

(TL = top-left, etc.)

(Check my algebra.  Sometimes I make small, stupid mistakes.  But you get the idea.)

Comment: Oh, you finish up with the obvious scaling to make the bottom-right quadrant an identity.  Rereading your question, what you want is slightly different.  But you should now be able to do what the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this problem for a while, this is what the question was meant to have you observe:

Gauss-Jordan usually progresses from the left-most column to the right-most column, one column at a time.  But there is no law that says you have to start with the left-most column.  You could instead compute a transform to introduce zeroes off the diagonal of the last column.  Then the next-to-last column, and so forth.  The problem is probably meant to make you think through that, and how that relates to standard Gauss-Jordan.

If that was the intent, then this is actually a really nice problem.